# Removed object in local storage array reappears when adding new object to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, local-storage

Currently a favorites function I have created with Vanilla JS works by storing the selected objects in local storage. But, when an object is removed, and then a new item is added to that same favorites array, both the original (removed) object and the newly added favorite show up in the viewport. I can confirm that both objects are removed from the array providing the data for the favorites section and then both show up when only one new object is added, but I do not know why this issue is occurring.

I have made sure to check that there is no overlap between my arrays. I print all objects that are added to the DOM into local storage for access with the favorites function and later cart functions. Included is the code for a favorites section-

Created item from original array object below-

```
function feetCard(array){

    document.getElementById('mainpageSectionforJS').innerHTML = "";

    let footCard = document.querySelector('#mainpageSectionforJS');
    console.log(array,"array name");

    localStorage.setItem("feetarray", JSON.stringify(array));
    console.log(array, "array name");
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("feetarray")); 
    console.log(data, "item data");

    data.forEach(component => {
        localStorage.setItem(component.valAssign, JSON.stringify(component))
    });

    data.forEach(component => {    
        footCard.innerHTML = footCard.innerHTML +
        `<div class="card card-margin" id="${component.valAssign}">
        <div class="card-header">
                <h4> ${component.name} </h4>
                <a class="kneeClick btn btn-primary" onclick="footFavorites(${component.valAssign})" > Add To Favorites </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                <img class="card-image" src="${component.image}"></img>
                <h5> Product Description </h5>
                <div>${component.manufacturer}</div>
                <div>${component.lcode1}</div>
                <div>${component.lcode2}</div>
                <div>${component.lcode3}</div>
                <div>${component.lcode4}</div>

                <div>${component.hdcode}</div>

                <div>$${component.cost}</div>
                <div>${component.reimbursement}</div>
                <div>${component.percent}</div>
                <div>${component.pdac}</div>


                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="${component.link}" target="_blank">${component.linkname}</a>
                <input type="button" class="additionSelectButton"></input>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
        console.log("Created", component.card, "Cards");
        });
        console.log("Card Creation Complete");

    };
```

Next, after clicking the favorites button-

```
footFavoritesArray = [];

function footFavorites(foot){
  console.log(foot, "foot object");

  console.log(foot.id, "foot id object");
      
      let getStoredFavorite = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(foot.id));
      console.log(getStoredFavorite, "retrieved cart item from local storage");
      // retrieve the stored favorite item
  
      footFavoritesArray.push(getStoredFavorite);
       console.log(footFavoritesArray, "local storage array with favorite item");
          // add the item to the cart array
        
        localStorage.setItem("Foot Favorites", JSON.stringify(footFavoritesArray))
          // push the cartArray to local storage
  
        let getFavorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Foot Favorites"));
        console.log(getFavorites, "local storage favorite array");
          // retrieve the stored array to check the values
          document.getElementById('footItemSectionJS').innerHTML = "";
          // clear the favorites viewport so the older items are removed, and redisplayed as a new one is added
          let favoritesLocation = document.querySelector('#footItemSectionJS');
          // document.getElementById('footItemSectionJS').innerHTML = getFavorites;
  
          // set the location where the favorite should show in the new configuration
  
          getFavorites.forEach(component => {    
            favoritesLocation.innerHTML = favoritesLocation.innerHTML +
           `<div class="card favorites card-margin" id="${component.valAssign}">
           <a class="footClick btn-small btn btn-primary" onclick="footCartItem(${component.valAssign})" > + Cart </a>
           <img class="card-image" src="${component.image}"></img>
  
              <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 id=""> ${component.name} </h4>
                  <a class="footClick btn btn-primary" onclick="removeFavorites(${component.valAssign})" > Remove Favorite </a>
                  <div id="">HD Code: ${component.hdcode}</div>
                  <h5><u> L-Codes </u></h5>
                  <div class="lcodes">
                  <div id="${component.lcode1}">${component.lcode1}</div>
                  <div id="${component.lcode2}">${component.lcode2}</div>
                  <div id="${component.lcode3}">${component.lcode3}</div>
                  <div id="${component.lcode4}">${component.lcode4}</div>
                  <div id="${component.lcode5}">${component.lcode5}</div>
                  <div id="${component.lcode6}">${component.lcode6}</div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>`;
          console.log("Created", component.card, "Cards");
          
          });
}
```

Then, remove that favorite-

```
function removeFavorites(item){

console.log(item[0].id, "item [0].id");
    
let getfavorite = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorites"));
console.log(getfavorite, "local storage favorite array");
// the favorites array to be modified
let favoriteSpread = {...getfavorite};
console.log(favoriteSpread, "favoriteSpread");


let parts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(item[0].id));
console.log(parts, "parts, the item created from the array item in local storage ");

let indexItem = getfavorite.map(object => object.valAssign).indexOf(item[0].id);
console.log(indexItem, "Index Item")

getfavorite.splice(indexItem, 1);
console.log(getfavorite, "getfavorite Array spliced")

// splice out the item from the favorite array. 

localStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(getfavorite));

// push the modified favoriteArray back to local storage

let showfavorite = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorites"));
console.log(showfavorite, "local storage favorite array");
// retrieve the favorite array back from local storage

        document.getElementById('footItemSectionJS').innerHTML = "";
        // clear the favorites viewport so the older items are removed, and redisplayed as a new one is added
        let favoritesLocation = document.querySelector('#footItemSectionJS');
        // document.getElementById('footItemSectionJS').innerHTML = getFavorites;

        // set the location where the favorite should show in the new configuration

        showfavorite.forEach(component => {    
          favoritesLocation.innerHTML = favoritesLocation.innerHTML +
         `<div class="card card-margin" id="${component.valAssign}">
         <a class="kneeClick btn-small btn btn-primary" onclick="cart(${component.valAssign})" > + Cart </a>
         <img class="card-image" src="${component.image}"></img>

            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 id=""> ${component.name} </h4>
                <a class="kneeClick btn btn-primary" onclick="removeFavorites(${component.valAssign})" > Remove Favorite </a>
                <div id="">HD Code: ${component.hdcode}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
        console.log("Created", component.card, "Cards");
        
        });
// display the retrieved array items in the "favorite" 
// reload the favorite and display it anew
}
```

last, here is a snapshot of what is occurring in my local storage-

First, saved favorite-

```
[
  {
    "valAssign": "abc",
    "manufacturer": "abc",
    "name": "abc",
  }
]
```

Second, removed-

[]

Third, add favorite of another item-

```
[
  {
    "valAssign": "abc",
    "manufacturer": "abc",
    "name": "abc",

  },
  {
    "valAssign": "def",
    "manufacturer": "def",
    "name": "def",
  }
]
```

also, in my local storage, the Value of the key/value pair looks like [,...] where other times it will be an object showing up in that line. Trying to provide as much information as possible.
Thanks for your help, this has stumped me.

Comment: try put `let footFavoritesArray = [];` inside `footFavorites` function.

Comment: `let footFavoritesArray = [];` is global variable. you always push data in it (`footFavoritesArray.push(getStoredFavorite);`), but never take removed data out. that's why you're seeing old data. when you remove item(s) from localstorage, you also need to remove those item(s) from `footFavoritesArray` as well.

Comment: It was a question of scope. Oh my goodness. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

as Layhout above answered for me, it was an issue of scope. I was not modifying the global array, only the locally stored one. That means that whenever I added a new item to the array I also added any globally stored array objects to local storage and those showed up on my viewport. Where I differed in his fix, which took me down the right path, is I am keeping the global array global, but modifying it with the function to remove a favorite. As follows-

```
footFavoritesArray = [];


    function footFavorites(foot){

      HERE IS THE ADDING FAVORITES FUNCTION (you can see the code above in  the 
          intial post)
          
          });

          footFavoritesArray = getFavorites;

       console.log(footFavoritesArray, "This is the modified global foot favorite 
      array")
      // change the global value of the array above
      // Above is the code to change the global array through the function, 
         notice the closing bracket is below this text.
     }

     function removeFootFavorites(item){

      THIS IS THE LOCATION OF THE REMOVE FAVORITE CODE
     
        });

footFavoritesArray = showfavorite;

console.log(footFavoritesArray, "This is the modified global foot favorite 
array")
// change the global value of the array above
// Above is the most important code, to change the global array to the value 
established by local storage. 
}
```